# How to change the size of a HTML button?

Tags: css, html

So I have this line of code put into Sublime Text:

```
<input id="MM" type="button" style="width: 150px" >
```

But how  do I change the length?

Comment: bad question. Not to mention this works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears what you're asking is how to make the button higher, since you have already found out how to make it wider. The answer to this is adding the "height:" CSS command inside of your "style" parenthesis:

```
<input id="MM" type="button" style="width: 150px; height: 50px;">
```

And editing the 50 after "height:" to the desired number will allow you to scale your button as big or small as you want.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check the developer options maybe your input button is reading other style... or you should put !important to your style.. something like this.. width: 150px !important;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase the height, give padding propert to input label.
[Please check here](https://jsfiddle.net/sree296/Lzk257vr/)

`<input type="button" value="submit" style="width:150px; padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px" />`*